# Eliminating elements in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm given a javascript array that has an amount (not specified) of various elements (strings, numbers, booleans). I need to eliminate strings and booleans. How should I approach it? Should I use `typeof`?

Comment: Yes, you should use _typeof_.

Comment: *"Should I use typeof?"* That would be the obvious thing to use, yes, probably with `Array#filter`.

Comment: n.b. `arr.filter` creates a new _Array_, it doesn't modify the existing _Array_. Make sure you save/return the reference to the result. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use `typeof`?

Yes, you should and chain the conditions with logical AND while testing for unequalness.

```js
var array = [NaN, 0, '0', undefined, null, false];

array = array.filter(function (a) {
    return typeof a !== 'string' && typeof a !== 'boolean';
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof` operator in `filter()` method callback, eg:

```
const myArray = [1,'foo',{name:'bar'},true];
myArray.filter(e => typeof e !== 'string' && typeof e !== 'boolean');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way using `typeof`   and  `array.filter()` function

```
    var getNone = x => typeof x !== 'string' && typeof x !=='boolean'; 
    var arr = ['henry',true,1,0,5,'charles',false].filter(getNone);
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this sort of filtering a lot, you can create a generic type filtering method. The method will receive as params, isType methods for types that will be filtered out.

```js
const array = [NaN, 0, 'string', undefined, null, false];

const isType = (type) => (v) => typeof v === type; // generic type method using partial application
const isString = isType('string'); // detects strings
const isBoolean = isType('boolean'); // detects booleans

const filterTypes = (arr, ...typesToFilter) => 
  arr.filter((v) => !typesToFilter.some((isType) => isType(v))); // remove all items that are of one of the typesToFilter

const result = filterTypes(array, isString, isBoolean);

console.log(result);
```